# Getting the Max count of a feld

Tags: mysql

Trying to get the count of the max pol_id from this query below.

I can get the max pol_id but cannot get the count when I put in count(max(pol_id))

Can anyone help.

```
select   max(pol_id)  FROM error_t e (NOLOCK)
join catalog_t  c
on e.pol_id = c.catalog_id
WHERE  e.err_num = '1'
and e.err_dsc = 'no catalog id'
```

Comment: max only return 1 value, why would you count a max ?
If you want to count the number of time the max appears. Maybe a subquery can do the trick.

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: So you are looking for the highest pol_id for which an error entry with `err_num = 1` and `err_dsc = 'no catalog id'` exists? And then you want to count how many such error entries exist for this id?

Comment: Hi maybe I didn't explain it great looking back. In the catalog table the pol_id can have more than one record. So using last_update_date I want to only count the most recent record

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @B.H: This doesn't seem to make much sense to me. In your query the pol_id is the catalog_id. So how can there be duplicates in the catalog table when it's the ID? And what is this last_update_date you are suddenly talking about? It doesn't exist in your query. Please Show some sample data. Some records for the two tables and the desired result with an explanation how to get to this result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, I think you want to count the number of time you have the max.

```
select   count(pol_id)  FROM error_t e (NOLOCK)
join catalog_t  c
on e.pol_id = c.catalog_id
where pol_id = (select max(pol_id)  FROM error_t e (NOLOCK)
join catalog_t  c
on e.pol_id = c.catalog_id
WHERE  e.err_num = '1'
and e.err_dsc = 'no catalog id');
```

Something along those lines. I am not really good in mysql so if someone have a better answer, feel free to post it.